# How to connect a client behind a NAT router to an Asterisk server behind a NAT router?

Tags: port-forwarding, nat, asterisk

I have an asterisk setup on a server. The local IP address is 172.22.9.200 and extenal IP address is 75.45.185.100. My client device is an android phone that is connected to a router and it which has NAT enabled in it. My router address is 27.770.345.670. I want to connect my client device to my server. I think setting up a STUN server would do it, but can I setup a STUN server on the same server where Asterisk is or is there any way to connect the client to the server without a STUN or TURN server ?

If I try to connect with my mobile internet, the connection is perfect. It is only that I cannot connect with my wifi connection.

Note : Since my server is on a remote location, I cannot do port forwarding on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use external stun or turn server

See public STUN list

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/STUN

But in your case you not need stun, you just need forward ports and inform asterisk about external ip.

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+SIP+NAT+solutions

Please note, you are reponsible for security of your setup. Firewall and iptables-based fail2ban setup is highly recommended.

Comment: I have setup a STUN server on the same virtual system where I have setup the asterisk server and I have given my host address as the STUN address. (net=host). It's running now, and on my softphone I have given the STUN address as 75.45.185.100 and port as 3478. But still I am not able to register my extensions on the server.

Comment: Use external stun. You still needed setup NAT (see other link) on asterisk.

Comment: this is what I've setup : http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ufb8J.png
Does this make sense to work ?

Comment: Sorry, debug is offtopic on SO. you have debug your NAT'ed environment yourself or hire expert. Correct setup of asterisk is on second link.

Answer (score 0):

VPN to your asterisk server - the best 'safe' route.

Bear in mind that allowing an asterisk box to be 'open' to the web is NOT a good idea.  Search for "$10,000 VOIP phone bill" if this is unclear to you...

Can your router VPN onto your server's network?

If you don't have access to either VPN or port forwarding on the remote server's end, there's really not a good alternative for a safe connection setup.

Comment: On the remote server when I tried to check for firewall :
`iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere  `
... So, I think, I have access to my server ?

Comment: so, I think the problem could be with my router. I can add port forwarding to my router here, But what will happen when I try to connect to my device outside my wifi area ?